# Could a Hormagaunt evolve naturally?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

This is a tyranid hormagaunt from Warhammer 40000:
[image]

What I am asking is: could a creature similar to a hormagaunt (six-limbed, chitin (or something similar) plating, roughly pony-sized, reptilian head/body) naturally evolve?

Comment: What sizes can they reach?

Comment: @Renan - up to 8 mm.  They are WarHammerEctoparasites.

Comment: Assume the readers have no idea what a hormagaunt is and what is capable of.

Comment: @Willk the question says "pony-sized" but you say 8mm. I must have been looking at the wrong ponies because there seems to be a mismatch here. Or did the question just scale them up from their original size?

Comment: @VLAZ - Probably they meant "My Little Pony".

Comment: @VLAZ it was a joke.  Warhammer 40k is a tabletop strategy game, and the figures are about 8mm.

Comment: @Ryan_L I am *very* confident they aren't. I've seen WH40K figurines and they are not tiny. I googled to verify and standard size from the base to the *eyes* of the model is around 28 mm. Although, this has been changed few times and the standard has apparently also been 25 mm as well as 32 mm at different points in time. The [models for the hormagaunts](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-EU/Tyranid-Hormagaunt-Brood-12-Models) are apparently 25 mm. So, I don't believe these models are smaller than the width of my index finger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  It doesn't seem like that ridiculous of a creature.  It's not that big.  There are crocodiles that weigh more than ponies, for instance.

It has some problems though, if you want it to be exactly like the Hormagaunts in Warhammer 40k.  First, no organic substance is going to be able to cut metal armor.  A blade has to be harder than the thing it's trying to cut.  If it's softer, it will either dull or break.  So those chitinous talons have to be harder than whatever Space Marine armor is made of.  But this creature didn't evolve alongside metal-wearing foes.  Evolution works in baby steps.  A creature more fit to survive is more likely to pass on its genes.  But in this case, a hormagaunt with 5% harder talons isn't appreciably more likely to survive when the armor it's trying to cut is 1000% harder.  There's a huge power gap here that natural selection just can't bridge, because it has to be done in one generation.  Second, is the acidic blood.  I can see how it'd be an advantage in a fight, but creatures spend 99% of their time *not fighting*.  Whatever mechanisms it uses to make its blood acidic, while not dissolving itself would be metabolically expensive, for very little gain.  It seems likely to me that hormagaunts with less-acidic blood would be more likely to pass on their genes, because they're wasting less of their calories on acidic blood and acid-proof veins.